# Does PhoneGap Build support iOS SDK 12.1?

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, phonegap, ios12

From the App Store Connect I noticed a message telling me that from **March 27, 2019** my applications will have to be built with the **iOS 12.1 SDK.**

So I searched for the version of Cordova that is compatible with this SDK and found [this message on Cordova's blog](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/09/cordova-ios-release-5.0.0.html).

I looked for the equivalent at PhoneGap Build and that's where I have a problem. According to [this PhoneGap Build support page](https://build.phonegap.com/current-support), the latest version supported by phonegap is **4.5.5** (iOS 11).

So I come to the information fishery to find out if the Phonegap Build service is ready for this change or if all their users will have to do their build at home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem as [PhoneGap Build already builds with Xcode version 10.1](https://build.phonegap.com/changelog). In the logs of one of my builds in PhoneGap Build I can see the following path:

> /Applications/Xcode101.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/**iPhoneOS12.1.sdk**/

Which to me suggests that PhoneGap Build is already able to build with the iOS 12.1 SDK, which is exactly what Apple is requesting:

> As a reminder, starting March 27, 2019 all new apps and app updates
>   for iPhone or iPad, including universal apps, will need to be **built
>   with the iOS 12.1 SDK** and support iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad
>   Pro (3rd generation).

I am not sure if you need to target a higher version of PhoneGap to achieve the same results. The default PhoneGap CLI version is currently 6.5.0, so if you need a higher version add the following to your `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.1.1" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it seems clearer now. To see if my updates will pass without any problem on Wednesday.